# hierarchical ACl with inheritance and override

Tags: php, mysql, inheritance, hierarchy, rbac

I am providing the scenario below where i am finding it hard to figure out how to create the DB structure to manage. Any guidance and solutions will be helpful

We have domains as the top level , multiple groups can be created under each domain , similarly multiple users can belong to each group in a domain.
We also have modules (eg. FAQ,Products etc) and actions like (add,edit,delete,view etc). Each module can have multiple actions as  (like Add_FAQ ,Edit_FAQ etc).

Case 1

We need to manage permissions for these module actions, permissions can be provided on domains,groups and users. If one domain is given permission to do something , all groups and users under it automatically are allowed. The permissions can be overridden by providing a group or user an individual permission opposite to what is given to its parent.An example situation would be like a domain X has 2 groups (grp1,grp2) and each group has 2 users user1_grp1,user2_grp1,user1_grp2,user2_grp2. Now X is allowed to delete FAQ , which means all groups and users are also allowed.Now grp1 is denied to delete FAQ and user2_grp2 is denied to delete FAQ. So finally only user1_grp2 is left to delete FAQ.
if a permission is not defined at a lower level , then parent permission will be considered.

Case 2

Similarly like permissions where we have only allow or deny, there is a need to manage settings & values eg., for a domain it is set to display 20 records at a time , but the value 20 can be overridden by 50 to a group or user under it. Which means that user and group would see 50 records at a time while rest all under that domain will have 20 records.

Can anyone help suggest how to manage it with Database. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to look at acl-magic.  https://github.com/salboaie/acl-magic
By creating hierarchies of groups (roles), resources and proper "concerns" you can model your usecase. The "persistence" side can be easily implemented with any database.